# sql query for calculating datetime difference of every ticket as time duration for each ticket

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column ticketid,owner,owndate.

```
ticketid owner          owndate
1050    REID        2004-09-15 09:50:41
1054    SINCLAIR    2004-09-15 09:52:14
1069    WILSON      2004-09-24 08:17:44
1069    REID        2004-09-24 08:17:55
1073    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 08:44:57
1026    (null)      2004-09-24 08:46:23
1074    REID        2004-09-24 08:55:31
1075    REID        2004-09-24 08:58:29
1028    REID        2004-09-24 08:59:09
1028    (null)      2004-09-24 08:59:44
1076    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 09:00:46
1029    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 09:01:54
1077    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 09:03:17
1078    REID        2004-09-24 09:05:12
1031    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 09:06:04
1084    REID        2004-09-24 09:10:22
1086    REID        2004-09-24 09:11:16
1088    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 09:16:52
1036    SINCLAIR    2004-09-24 09:17:38
1089    REID        2004-09-24 09:18:31
1037    REID        2004-09-24 09:22:57
1004    (null)      2004-09-24 09:24:21
1041    REID        2004-09-24 09:57:47
```

I want to display output columns as ticketid,timeduration1,timeduration2,timeduration3...
where timeduration is time difference between two consecutive row for particular ticketid as...

```
ticketid     timeduration1     timeduration2         timeduration3     ...
1001        1min 43sec       4min 18sec        74days 19hrs 34min 59sec ...
```

Comment: ticket id 1001 doesn't even appear in your sample data, please create a verifiable example.

Comment: There are many ticketid from 1001 to 1200. I have displayed some of the rows from table.

Comment: the point i was making was that nobody can look at that sample data and produce the desired output, because the values you want aren't present in the sample data to enable the calulcations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have made the query with perfect output.

```
select ticketid,
owner1=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner2-owner1,108),
owner2=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner3-owner2,108),
owner3=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner4-owner3,108),
owner4=CONVERT(varchar(10),owner4,108)from
(
select ticketid,owndate,'owner'+cast(ROW_NUMBER() over 
(partition by ticketid order by owndate) as varchar(10)) as sno from   tkownerhistory                
) tbl
pivot
(
max(owndate)
for sno in(owner1,owner2,owner3,owner4)
)pvt'
```